# After i backup and restore my db in mysql i cant see my blob file

Tags: java, mysql, blob

Hi I'm having an issue with my program, it has a user login that includes a picture for each user that gets saved in a data base at first when I create a user and login with that user i can see the picture for that user but once i backup my data base and restore it and i try logging in again it works fine just that it doesn't show the user picture anymore can anyone help me please.

This is my backup code:

```
try{
                Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
                File backupFile = new File(String.valueOf(RealizarBackupMySQL.getSelectedFile().toString())
                        +"_"+fecha+".sql");
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(backupFile);
                Process child = runtime.exec("C:\\xampp\\mysql\\bin\\mysqldump --opt  --password= --user=root --databases cesamo  -R"); 
                InputStreamReader irs = new InputStreamReader(child.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(irs);

                String line;
                while( (line=br.readLine()) != null ) {
                    fw.write(line + "\n");
                }
                fw.close();
                irs.close();
                br.close();
```

And this is my restore code:

```
String dbUserName = "root";// username
        String dbPassword = "";//Password
        
        String[] restoreCmd = new String[]{"C:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysql.exe ", "--user=" + dbUserName, "--password=" + dbPassword, "-e", "source " + path};
        Process runtimProcess;
        try {
            runtimProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(restoreCmd);
            int proceCom = runtimProcess.waitFor();
```

this is the code i use to retrieve the img from the DB into a jlabel:

```
String sql="select foto from login where usu='"+txtUsuario.getText()+"'";
        try{
            PreparedStatement pst = (PreparedStatement) registro.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs=pst.executeQuery();

while(rs.next()){
    Blob blob = rs.getBlob("foto");
         byte[] content = blob.getBytes(1L,(int)blob.length());
         ImageIcon imi = new ImageIcon(content);
         Image img = imi.getImage();
         Image newimg = img.getScaledInstance(lblfoto1.getWidth(), lblfoto1.getHeight(), java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
         imi = new ImageIcon(newimg);
```

Comment: first of all you have to check your database, is there exist the blob data or not

Comment: yea i checked it and its there

Comment: which type data/image saved as blob?

Comment: i use jpeg and  png

Comment: How did you back up the database? How did you restore the backup? Were there any errors or warnings while backing up or restoring?

Comment: no i don't get any errors at all. I just edited my question so you can see my backup & restore code up top

Comment: a bit far from topic: another way to use images could be to store the path of the image in the database instead of the image itself

Comment: after the restore did you verify the database that the image exists and not lost during restore? @Edx

Comment: yea i verified it and its still there thats why im confused

Answer (score 0):

I got it.
It turns out that the code i was using to backup the DB, while it didn't show any error it may have been incomplete, I still don't understand why it didn't work because as i stated before that even after i backed it up and restored it i check to see if the blob file was present in the DB and it was but for some reason it didn't want to show.

But once i changed the code thank God now its working:

````
String dbHost = "localhost"; 
    String dbPort = "3306";
        String dbName = "cesamo";
        String dbUser = "root";
        String dbPass = "";
        String dumpExe = "C:\\xampp\\mysql\\bin\\mysqldump";
        String dumpSavePath = txtruta.getText();

  batchCommand = dumpExe + 
                         " -h " + dbHost + 
                         " --port " + dbPort + 
                         " -u " + dbUser + 
                         " --password=" + dbPass + 
                         " --add-drop-database -B " + dbName + 
                         " -r \"" + dumpSavePath + "\\" + nom.getText()+"_"+fecha+".sql";   
            ```
````